# Putting an object in my Database C#

Tags: c#, database, async-await

I'm trying to put an object into my database, and I was wondering if this was possible.
Currently this is my code

```
  private async void SaveSchedule()
    {

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
           IList<Item> lstABC = LstSchedule.ToList();
            foreach(Item i in LstSchedule)
            {
                lstABC.Add(i);
            }

           Session s = new Session();
           s.Name = Text;
           s.Items = lstABC;
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://******:****/api/session", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                int result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(jsonresponse);
            }
        }
```

Though the Issue here is that my s.Items is a list with objects in it with let's say x, y and z in it

How can I get it into my db like Name = Text, Items = object1x,object1y,object1z ; object2x,object2y,object2z...

This is the model for session:

```
 public class Session
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you should read a little about one to many relationships in relational databases

Comment: `Items = object1x,object1y,object1z ; ` ... NO, never store `,` delimited values in database. Think about re-designing your table in that case.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I know that, in my actual database, the commas are spaces

Comment: The general answer to the question *Can I put an object into a database?* will be *Yes, you can!*... The question is what you want to do with it later on. You COULD just serialize your object into JSON and put that into a string column... Except you won't be able to make any use of the magic features which relational databases provide. So you really need to expand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public async Task<Uri> Post<T>(T obj, Uri url)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, obj);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();             
            return response.Headers.Location;
        }
    }
```